# Find the clicked li number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a standard list.

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">blah 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">blah 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">blah 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">blah 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery:

```js
$('ul li a').live('click', function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent('li');
});
```

What I want to find out is the parent li's position in the list of the clicked link e.g. clicking on blah 3 would give me 2, blah 4 would give 3 etc.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$('ul li a').live('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).parent('li').index());
});
```

Will give you what you want, but keep in mind these are 0 based indexes -- ie the first line item is index 0, the last line item is 3.

[jQuery index() method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 3):

you can get the index of an element with [jquery`s index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$('ul li a').live('click', function() 
{
    var index =  $(this).index();
});
```

Comment: This gives you the a element not the li element.. so use parent() to get the index of li as the correct answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

No need to jQueryfy this :

```
$('ul li a').live('click', function() {
    var position = 0;
    var currentNode = this;
    var firstNode = currentNode.parentNode.firstChild;
    while(firstNode != currentNode) {
        position++;
        currentNode = currentNode.previousSibling;
    }
    alert(position);
});
```

Comment: If there's no need to "jQueryfy", then why use _some_ jQuery (selector), but not take full advantage..?

Comment: Because the first poster already use jQuery to attach his event.
But to get some position using $'s functions (which, if I'm not wrong, do more than selecting things) may be a little too much.
jQueryfy the things which are not the same in some browsers (CSS selects, events handling etc.) but use simple, portable and fast javascript when possible.

Comment: This won't always give the same answer as jQuery's `index()`, since it it's not filtering for actual elements and will include text/comment nodes in the count. Could use `firstElementChild` and `previousElementSibling` depending on intended browser support.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but [`.live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) is now deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

The alternative is to use [`.delegate`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('ul li').delegate('a','click', function() {

    alert($(this).parent('li').index());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li a').live('click', function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent('li');
        alert(parent.prevAll('li').size());
    });
});
```

Comment: Novel approach, but I imagine index() is faster.