# how to add content to the specific ul of whose parent li is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add some content  to  of whose parent li has been clicked and remove innerhtml of any previous li that was clicked?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testtab.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $('#chat ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
     alert("in");
     alert($(this).closest('li').index());
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chat" class="chat">
    <ul class="chatmenu">
        <li id="one" class="users"><a href="#one">abcy<span class="notify">1 new*</span></a>
            <div class="chattng">
                <ul class="overl">

                </ul>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li id="two" class="users"><a href="#two">avvv<span class="notify">a</span></a>
            <div class="chattng">
                <ul class="overl">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="three" class="users"><a href="#three">gtt<span class="notify">d</span></a>
        </li>
        <li id="four" class="users"><a href="#four">trt<span class="notify">e</span></a></li>
        <li id="five" class="users"><a href="#five">kkk<span class="notify">f</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
 </html>
```

once it's known then how to do that whichever li is clicked it's innerhtml gets something and the previous li that was clicked has innerthtml as null?

Comment: And what's not working with what you've got? If you're using jQuery < 1.9 then `live()` should work (albeit it's deprecated), if you're using 1.9 then use `on()` instead.

Comment: live() has been removed which jquery version you are using

Answer (score 2):

Youre using `live` on a version which doesnt support it. Use `on`.

```
 $('#chat ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
     alert($(this).closest('li').index());
 });
```

You must wrap this is `ready` handler for it to trigger when the elements inside `#chat` are ready and initialized.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#chat ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
         alert($(this).closest('li').index());
   });
});
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/Rr2dP/

Or, you could bind this event to the `document` object :

```
$(document).on('click', '#chat ul li a' ,function (e) {
    alert($(this).closest('li').index());
});
```

This is what `live` used to do.

Could someone go edit this question? [Find the clicked li number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927592/find-the-clicked-li-number)
This is source of this info. We dont want ppl following outdated info now do we?

Comment: His script tag @DavidThomas :  `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You must wrap this function with `document.ready`. did u do that @user2425783

Comment: $(document).ready($('#chat ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
     alert("in");
     alert($(this).closest('li').index());

 }));

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the function inside `$(document).ready();`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#chat ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
 alert("in");
 alert($(this).closest('li').index());
 });
});
</script>
```